# 'refresh' pagination vs 'soft' ajax pagination

Tags: pagination

Someone can explain why sites like stackoverflow are using 'classical' pagination rather than AJAX pagination?

- I mean with classical pagination the common links on bottom of the page to nex page, last page, etc. Sample: [stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagination)
- AJAX pagination will be like [datables control](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: They only people who could answer this properly are the people who created/maintain Stack Overflow. So unless they stop by here, I am not sure you will get a good answer.

Comment: We can only make assumptions. If you want to know reasoning behind certain design decisions of sites in the Stack Exchange platform then you can look over posts at http://meta.stackexchange.com as that's the site for discussing Stack Exchange the platform.

Answer (score 1):

I would think advertisements would be the number one reason.

Possibly also just legacy stuff. maybe the data isn't available in a format that makes sense to deliver via ajax and there's no real significant pay off to switching it.

Comment: Nice argument (advertisements). I don't believe on legacy stuff on sites like this.